# Promoting code through environments in AWS Fargate

Tags: devops, circleci, aws-fargate

I have a scheduled job that I want to run in AWS Fargate. I have so far setup a CloudWatch schedule that runs a lambda function that starts the task. I'm using a task definition for each of my environments, but I'm struggling to find an easy way for our QA and PM to promote code from the dev environment to QA, Staging, and Prod. Each environment will have its own CloudWatch rule and its own lambda function.

How can I setup deployments to each environment, preferably without building a web interface tool that will allow them to select versions from a dropdown or something? I also have to consider that each environment will need its own environment variables that may need to change on the fly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We're going to be using CircleCI's approval hold to manage deployment to each environment. This solution doesn't offer any easy rollback of versions, but documentation can be found [here](https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/workflows/#holding-a-workflow-for-a-manual-approval).